# scheduling spring stream listener to avoid downtimes

Tags: spring-cloud-stream

I have a stream listener listening to a rabbit mq and doing insert/update operations based on the input msg and persisting it to an underlying Db2 database. The database has a weekly downtime for 6 hours. How do I schedule the listener not to run during this time frame, so that I don't lose the input msg. Keep in mind that this msg is sent from upstream in the rabbit queue in an async context, so I can't ask upstream to repost/retry after the downtime.

```
@StreamListener(target = Sink.INPUT)
public void testListener(byte[] msg)
{
    System.out.println(new String(msg));
    try{
        int count = zoneInsert(mapper.readValue(msg, OrderDTO.class));
        System.out.println("inserted "+count+" row");
    }catch(Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Right now, not much. We are adding support for lifecycle control in 2.0. Two hacks for this would be: 
1. stop your listening application (if possible)
2. Divert error messages to a DLQ and schedule a DLQ app to start right after the DB comes back to life